# Drinfeld basis of the universal formal deformation of a supersingular elliptic curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Now I'm trying (5.3.2) of Katz-Mazur's Arithmetic moduli of elliptic curves.

> Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p > 0$, $E_0$ a supersingular elliptic curve over $k$, and $E/W[[T]]$ the universal deformation of $E$.
>   (Where $W$ is the Witt vector ring with the residue field $k$.)
>   Let $A$ be a finite $W[[T]]$-algebra which is local, $\mathfrak{E} = E \times_{W[[T]]} A$, $P, Q \in \mathfrak{E}(A)$ be a Drinfeld $p^n$-basis
>   (i.e., a pair of points such that $\mathfrak{E}[p^n] = \sum_{(a,b) \in (\mathbb{Z}/p^n)^2} [aP + bQ]$ as Cartier divisors), and $X$ be a parameter of the formal group of $\mathfrak{E}$.
>   Then $P, Q$  both lie in the formal group of $\mathfrak{E}$.
>   So let $f = X(P), g = X(Q) \in \mathfrak{m}_A$.
>   Then for an artinian local ring $R$ with the residue field $k$ and for a map $A \to R$ with $f, g \mapsto 0$, we have $P \times_A R = Q \times_A R = 0$.

Does the word "$P$ lies in the formal group" mean that $P : \operatorname{Spec}A \to \mathfrak{E}$ induces $\operatorname{Spf}A \to \hat{\mathfrak{E}}$?
And if so, how can I show it?

I know the Grothendieck existence theorems.
(In particular $\operatorname{Hom}(X, Y) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(\hat{X}, \hat{Y})$ over a complete noetherian local ring.)
But $\hat{\mathfrak{E}}$ is the formal completion along the $0$-section, not along $\mathfrak{m}_A \mathscr{O}_{\mathfrak{E}}$.
So we cannot apply it.

And I know that since $E_0$ is supersingular, $P \times k = Q \times k = 0 \in E_0(k)$.

Comment: Where is the quote taken from? What is a Drinfeld $p^n$-basis?

Comment: The formal completion on the zero section should equal the formal completion on the maximal ideal since the base ring $A$ is already complete.

Comment: @WillSawin Thank you very much! Would you explain it in a little more detail? I think that in order to show that the completion along the 0 section and one along $\mathfrak{m}_A$ are the same, we need these two closed subsets are the same.
And now this fails.

Comment: It's not true that to show two completions are the same, you need the two closed subsets to be the same.

Comment: @WillSawin For a nice scheme $X$ and its closed subset $Z$, the fomal completion along $Z$ is the space $Z$ with some sheaf of rings.
So I think we need it.

Comment: No, in the affine / local case, we're just talking about a ring, not a space with a sheaf of rings.

Comment: @WillSawin Sorry, I don't understand. What should I show?
The completion along 0 is the topological space $\operatorname{Spec}A$ with the sheaf $\lim \mathscr{O}/\mathscr{I}^n$, where $\mathscr{I}$ is the sheaf of ideals corresponding to the 0 section.
One along $\mathfrak{m}_A$ is the topological space $E_0$ with the sheaf of rings $\lim \mathscr{O}/\mathfrak{m}^n \mathscr{O}$.
These are completely different.
(These underlying spaces have different dimensions. And so it seems to be nonsense to say that these sheaves are isomorphic or not.)

Comment: Just show the global sections are isomorphic (at least to start).